# Which is the best Python version and IDE for me to use?

Tags: python, ide

Based on my project, which is the best version of Python to use? Which is the best IDE to use that runs on Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows? Here is the background for these questions:

I'm building a small application GUI that features "drill-down" views and direct manipulation on personalized calendars. Should I use Python 3, the newest version, or an older version is better at this GUI task? I've heard that some of the old GUI libraries do not support the new version yet, but not quite sure if this will matter a lot. Could you please name the libraries that might be relevant? Even better if you could suggest your preferred IDE either under Windows or Ubuntu. Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on which GUI you use.  If you're using PyQt, it [supports v3](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/python_v3.html).  wxPython, however, [does not](http://wiki.wxpython.org/TentativeRoadmap).

As a rule of thumb, for now, you can pretty much use python 3.0 syntax in 2.7, and keep things compatible going forward.  I'd say, except for print statements, the differences aren't that mind-blowingly different between 2-3.  IDE's pretty much support both - and gnud's links are pretty good for that.

**Popularity**

- When selecting a framework to learn, popularity is a reasonable gauge of how good a framework is, and how easy it will be to get support when you run into problems.  The [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) on stackoverflow are a quick way to get a ballpark idea.

**Environment**

- Start with what you're the most familiar with.  When learning something new, there is so much to absorb, that having something familiar really helps.
- For example, when I taught myself python a year ago, I used pydev in eclipse, because I've been a cross-platform java developer using eclipse for quite some time.  Made life much easier.
- If you're starting from ground zero, it doesn't matter very much.  Pick something popular that you feel comfortable in and start coding.  As you become familiar with what you're doing, you'll be able to compare other packages and determine if it's right to switch.
- The popular IDE's are cross-platform.  Graphics packages too, although usually one is stronger on unix or windows.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your opinion. I'm not sure if I've found something useful but here is one GUI library that seems to be good for beginners. Have you heard of this? http://page.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Haven't heard of it, but if you know Tcl/Tk it might at least be more familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vim](http://justinlilly.com/vim/vim_and_python.html) as IDE.Start program with 2.7 version with 3.0 in mind.Have a look at this [python 2 or 3](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with 2.7 since most libraries work with it. The differences between both are not too big, so you might even be able to switch if you want to in the future. But before you choose Python 3 and you find a library you really want to use and it's not available for Python 3 you would regret choosing.

wxPython and PyQt are pretty popular. wxPython doesnt support 3 yet...

I prefer PyCharm it's not free but it's so great and it has so many features...
One of the best code-completion i ever had for Python.

P.S.: if its really simple you mgiht even consider using tkinter.

Comment: Thank you cwoebker. Have you heard of this? page.sourceforge.net

Comment: Could you take a look at page.sourceforge.net? Is it a GUI builder library or an IDE? Or both? Thanks.

Comment: its gui builder for tkinter which comes from tcl... so you would use it to simplify the process in building guis with tkinter, and no its not an ide

Answer (score 0):

[SublimeText2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has excellent Python support.

Also you can use [PyDev for Eclipse](http://pydev.org/).

About versions: I think you should write 2.7-compatible code, but be ready( and know how) to update it to 3.2 or later.